# How to change columns shown in File Open dialog

Tags: finder

I am using Thunderbird and the *File Open* dialog shows *Date Added*  . I would like to change to *Last Modified* (or the equivalent) .  Is this a *Finder* setting, *macOS* or *Thunderbird* specific?  How can that setting be changed?

[image]

Comment: I do not have **Thunderbird**, however, in a normal **Finder** _window_ in _column view_ one can _right-click_ on the _column headers_ and select from _options_ available. Try it while in  **Thunderbird**.

Comment: @user3439894 Yes that works . I accepted Steve Chambers' answer that says the same thing

Comment: RE: " I accepted Steve Chambers' answer that says the same thing " --  That's fine, I have no problem with that. -- Since I didn't have **Thunderbird** to test and be absolutely sure, I chose to post it as a comment instead of posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When that dialog is displayed you can indeed choose what fields are displayed.

Just right-click on one of the column headings (next to "Name, Size," etc) and select from the list in the pop-up menu.

It should remember that selection, at least for that app.

Comment: Came back to this (I'm the OP) 30 months later and again made good use of it. Can I upvote again given multiple years have passed?

Comment: Well thx but each account is (I believe) restricted to down/upvoting any one comment or question **once,** though you can take back an up/downvote you previously gave.

Comment: Yea it was not a serious question here - just a manner of expressing appreciation